# NAS appearing twice in "Other locations"

Tags: networking, file-sharing, nas

I have a Synology DiskStation inside my LAN. I have called it "pluto".

When I go to the file explorer and watch at "Other Locations" I see this twice. Why could this be?

[image]

Comment: Does the device share via multiple protocols by any chance (CIFS and AFP, or CIFS and NFS)?

Comment: Not sure about it... how can I find out?

Comment: Probably easiest to check on the NAS itself [Control Panel > File Services > SMB/AFP/NFS](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_winmacnfs_desc)

Comment: AFP and SMB are turned on